# Reference Error in Conditional Compilation

Tags: c#, .net

I have more than one class library in my Monolit .net6 project. In my config file, I specify which library the project should use.

By specifying a condition in .csproj in my API project, I want the reference of the library I will work with to be added. Because I do not want unnecessary files to appear in my publishing file.

My code is like this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
     <DefineConstants>PROVINCE_Test1</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(DefineConstants)' == 'PROVINCE_Test1'">
         <ProjectReference Include="..\\Test1.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>

  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(DefineConstants)' == 'PROVINCE_Test2'">
    <ProjectReference Include="..\\Test2.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
 
</Project>
```

No problem so far.
The problem I'm having is in this program.cs

```
if (source == "Test1")
{
   builder.Services.AddTest1Module();
}
else if (source == "Test2")
{
   builder.Services.AddTest2Module();
}
```

I have such a definition.
This definition of `.AddTest1Module()` and `.AddTest2Module();` gives errors because their references are added conditionally. It cannot find the relevant library.

How do I solve this error or is what I'm trying to do correct?

Libraries have no relationship with each other. They are two independent class libraries.

I tried this code but it didn't recognize Test

```
#if PROVINCE_Test1
  using Test1;
#endif
```

Comment: In c#, things should be a little more predictable for a library. Why not create 2 libraries?

Comment: Sounds like you are cramming 2 products into one. So, if one version uses Lib1 and the other uses Lib2, then it _should_ be rather safe to say, they do roughly the same thing in your product, do they? So, I personally would probably extract one "Abstraction" Lib as an interface against which I can code, and then have 2 wrapping libs, that implement those abstractions _using_ Lib1 or Lib2 respectively. Then, you can just use _one_ `services.AddTestModule()` and execute will automagically the one that's actually referenced.

Comment: What is the condition?  When should the first library be used and when the second? Since checking for inexistent labels is not a requirement in itself, is the one library to be used with a specific .net version or something similiar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(DefineConstants)' == 'PROVINCE_Test1'">
    <ProjectReference Include="..\\Test1.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(DefineConstants)' == 'PROVINCE_Test2'">
    <ProjectReference Include="..\\Test2.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

is a **compile-time** condition, whereas this

```
if (source == "Test1")
{
   builder.Services.AddTest1Module();
}
else if (source == "Test2")
{
   builder.Services.AddTest2Module();
}
```

is a **run-time** condition. Since the compiler cannot know which value `source` will have at run time, both `AddTest1Module` and `AddTest2Module` must be available at compile time.

To fix this, you can use **conditional compilation** in your C# code:

```
#if PROVINCE_Test1
   builder.Services.AddTest1Module();
#endif

#if PROVINCE_Test2
   builder.Services.AddTest2Module();
#endif
```

This also means that you no longer need to keep your .csproj constants and the value of `source` in sync: Only the former one is relevant, and you don't need the latter one any more.